# Integer solutions to diophantine equation $x^4+4x^3y-6x^2y^2-4xy^3+y^4=1$

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, roots, diophantine-equations, quartics

While working on some research, I needed to find the integer solutions to the polynomial 
$x^4+4x^3y-6x^2y^2-4xy^3+y^4=1$. I found $(0,1)$, $(0,-1)$, $(1,0)$, $(-1,0)$, $(3,2)$, $(-3,-2)$, $(2,-3)$, $(-2,3)$. These seem to be all, but can I prove this? 
I factored the equation several ways. I have:
$(x+y)^4-4xy^2(3x+2y)=1$, $(x-y)^4-4x^2y(3y-2x)=1$, and $x^4+2xy(2x+y)(x-2y)+y^4=1$.
Any suggestions? Even if I could find some bounds for possible solutions, that would be great.

Comment: You can use MathJax in the title, too.

Comment: Take the form $(x+y)^4-4xy^2(3x+2y)=1$, suppose $x+y=T$ you get a Pell like equation as $(T^2)^2 -4x(3x+2y) y^2=1$, compare it with pell equation $x^2- D y^2=1$ which can have infinitely many distinct integer solutions. $D=4x(3x+2y)$ can have particular values.

Comment: For $|x|,|y|\le 10^4$, no further solutions exist.

Comment: According to the thue-command in PARI/GP, the list is complete.

Comment: Isn't there a limit to the number of solutions to a Pell-like equation if x is a perfect square? That is, isn't there a finite number of solutions to $x^4-dy^2=1$?

Comment: @vrt The main problem with the Pell-approach is that $D$ depends on $x$ and $y$, which is not the case in a usual Pell-equation. So I don't think such an approach leads to anywhere.

Comment: @Peter I realised the same thing. But you've been helpful, as have the others who posted. Thank you!